# What is the best or fastest way to compare two strings?

Tags: c++, string, performance

I am not sure how fast the below code is. If anyone knows the faster/optimized code than this, please let me know.

```
int xstrcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
  while (*s1 == *s2++)
            if (*s1++ == 0)
                    return (0);
  return (*(const unsigned char *)s1 - *(const unsigned char *)(s2-1));
}
```

Comment: How large are the strings you're comparing? Where do they come from?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If not use the one supplied by the vendor. They probably have more tricks up their sleves that can make use of the processor/compiler idiosyncrasies

Comment: How to find out the code given by vendor??

Comment: The signature of your function is wrong: the arguments shall be `char const*`.

Comment: I wonder if anybody has compared a Monte Carlo alogrithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_algorithm) to the usual method for this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `::strcmp` instead of your own hand-rolled version. Your compiler vendor has most likely an assembly-only version which uses CPU-specific features for comparison (SSE4.2 for instance has special instructions for fast string comparison.) The MSVC version is written in assembly for instance and uses larger compares (whole words instead of individual characters) as much as possible, special casing unaligned starts/ends of the string (if you have VS2010 installed, it's in `VC/crt/src/intel/strcmp.asm`.)

Comment: Actually, I've been told not to use any built in function. I have to write my own string compare version :(

Comment: I am just developing my concepts...so i opt not to choose any built in function.

Comment: You won't beat the built-in functions in performance, but it surely doesn't matter at all. If you are just playing around, your strcmp implementation is good enough, all further speedups are rather complicated.

Comment: I can understand you wanting to write something like this all by yourself... reinventing the wheel can be a very satisfactory experience. But if that's the case, isn't asking other people to provide their code a form of cheating? On the other hand, if it's performance you're after, nothing beats the built in routines. So what is it you want to do?

Comment: The code given in this path: VC/crt/src/intel/strcmp.asm   and the code written by me.  Which one is better???

Comment: Well, the hand-written assembly is better, but yours is probably not too far off. What are you trying to achive? A reasonably fast strcmp? You're done, yours is as good as any. The fastest possible strcmp? Then you would have to start with the assembly version and tweak it for modern CPUs, etc. But on small strings, it's highly unlikely you'll end up with something faster than the years of optimization that went into the built-in strcmp.

Comment: Thanks Anteru.  So, now i am stopping to further optimize my code. :)

Answer (score 5):

Have you measured how much faster this is than strcmp? C strcmp should already be well optimized.

Some other methods you could take:

- Use memcmp if you already know the length of the strings.
- Compare 4 or 8 chars at a time by reinterpreting strings as int32 or int64 arrays, and handling the remainder chars as chars.

  - You may have issues if your pointers point to non 4-byte or 8-byte aligned memory, so compare as chars until you reach alignment

Comment: I dont know how to measure how fast my code is.  I am sure this code can't be fastest.

Comment: You can write a test program that does strcmp and your xstrcmp millions of times on random strings. Then, run a profiler on the code (e.g. google's gperf).

Answer (score 5):

If I'm testing for equality, sometimes I write this:

```
if (a[0]==b[0] && strcmp(a, b)==0){.....
```

so it will only call `strcmp` if the first characters match, which most of the time they don't.

Comment: This is useless, this would be already in the implementation of strcmp: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12136398/4641479

Comment: @StefanRein: But there is overhead in calling the function. That's what this is trying to save. In most cases it doesn't matter, but in a case where this consumes a significant percent of time, it does matter.

Comment: Isn't it also fairly likely that strcmp would get inlined?

Comment: @Nik: I always do [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771) to see what's taking time. If I see `strcmp` on the stack more than once, I know it's taking significant time and it's not in-lined. If it is in-lined, I may see it in the initial instructions of `strcmp`, Otherwise, it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: @Nik: I just saw the @Anteru answer. You can see that `strcmp` tries real hard to be optimal in the case where the strings are equal and are long. That's a lot of overhead to handle what is usually an unlikely case. In my experience, there are lots of short strings differing most of the time in the first character.