# C++ How to compare strings with pointers ignoring whitespaces?

Tags: c++

I have to compare 2 char strings... ignoring the whitespaces in it, so e.g:

```
int cmp("a b c ", "abc") == 0;
```

if both are same , return 0;

```
else if s1 is bigger than s2, return 1; else return -1; e.g:
int cmp(" aaab", "aaa") == 1;

int cmp("aaa" , "aa  ab") == -1;
```

how can I realise this with passing the strings as pointers and with pointerarithmetics ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int strcmp_ign_ws(const char * s1, const char * s2) {
    int count1(0);
    int count2(0);  

    while (*s1 != '\0' || *s2 != '\0') {            

    if (*s1 == '\0') //if s1 finished, do nothing
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (*s2 == '\0') //if s2 finished, do nothing
    {
        continue;
    }

    if ( *s1 == ' ' ) {
        s1++;           //if whitespace, go on to next char
    }

    if (*s2 == ' ') {
        s2++;           //if whitespace, go on to next char
    }

    if (*s1 == *s2) {  //if same chars, increase counters;go to next char
        s1++;
        s2++;
        count1++;
        count2++;
    }
    if (*s1 > *s2) {
        count1++;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    if (*s1 < *s2) {
        count2++;
        s1++;
        s2++;
    }
    /**
        while (*s1 == *s2) {
            if (*s1 == 0) 
            {
                return 0;
            }
            s1++;
            count1++;
            s2++;
            count2++;
        }**/


}
    return (count1 - count2);
```

}

int main() {

```
char a[] = "Hallo Welt!!!";
char b[] = "Hallo Welt";

int result(0);

result = strcmp_ign_ws(a,b);

cout << result << endl;

return 0;
```

}

EDIT: I may only use strlen , no other inbuilt functions... or strings

Comment: Your idea is sound but it may have implementations issues. **Which is the exact problem that you are having**? Which is your question?

Comment: I dont know why I get wrong results out...

Comment: is this a homework problem again?

Comment: yes it is ................

Answer (score 3):

At the first step, replace those two first `continue` by `break`. Otherwise it goes to an infinite loop. You're increment-ing those pointers in the loop but once check them against `\0`. To skip white space you need to use inner loops too.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12136398) `strcmp` implementation, I've made some changes and then:

```
int strcmp_ign_ws(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    const unsigned char *p1 = (const unsigned char *)s1;
    const unsigned char *p2 = (const unsigned char *)s2;

    while (*p1)
    {
        while (isspace(*p1)) p1++;
        if (!*p1) break;

        while (isspace(*p2)) p2++;
        //if (!*p2) break;

        if (!*p2) return  1;
        if (*p2 > *p1) return -1;
        if (*p1 > *p2) return  1;

        p1++;
        p2++;
    }

    if (*p2) return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This returns -1 for strings which are identical, except for different whitespace at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The usual idea for this algorithm is:

```
int strcmp_ign_ws(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  const char *p1 = s1, *p2 = s2;

  while (true) {
    while (*p1 != '\0' && isspace((unsigned char)*p1)) p1++;
    while (*p2 != '\0' && isspace((unsigned char)*p2)) p2++;
    if (*p1 == '\0' || *p2 == '\0') {
      return (*p2 == '\0') - (*p1 == '\0');
    }
    if (*p1 != *p2) {
      return (unsigned char)*p2 - (unsigned char)*p1;
    }
    p1++;
    p2++;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me, but what if I now want to compare the content of the chars with eachother ? lets say aac and aab , => aac>aab => return 1 ??

Comment: I don't understand your question. Comparing the characters is exactly what the last `if` condition does.

Comment: the last if case is never being executed, is that right? looks like poor code...