# C - strcmp related to an if statement

Tags: c, string, function, if-statement, strcmp

In the code below I use strcmp to compare two strings and make this comparison the condition of an if statement.
With the code below, the output will be `hello world`, because string "one" is equal to string "two".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char one[4] = "abc";
char two[4] = "abc";

int main() {

    if (strcmp(one, two) == 0) {
        printf("hello world\n");
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the program, and make it print `hello world` if the two string are different so I change the program that way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char one[4] = "abc";
char two[4] = "xyz";

int main() {

    if (strcmp(one, two) == 1) {
        printf("hello world\n");
    }
}
```

I dont understand the reason why it does not print out anything.

Comment: Change `if (strcmp(one, two) == 1)` to `if (strcmp(one, two) != 0)`.

Comment: @EdHeal you are perfectly right, I was so sure that it returns 1 if strings are not equal, sorry, next time it will be the first thing i will do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `strcmp()` will return a negative integer in this case.

So change this:

```
if (strcmp(one, two) == 1) {
```

to this:

```
if (strcmp(one, two) != 0) {
```

to take into account all the cases that the strings differ.

Notice that you could have spotted that yourself by either reading the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) or by printing what the functions returns, like this:

```
printf("%d\n", strcmp(one, two));
// prints -23
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct behaviour is:

```
if (strcmp(one, two) != 0) {
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```

Actually, this function returns the *difference* between two strings:

- < 0: the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2.
- 0: the contents of both strings are equal
- > 0: the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2.

[This is an example of how strcmp could be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12136398/2489715)

Answer (score 2):

According to the C Standard (7.23.4.2 The strcmp function)

> 3 The strcmp function returns **an integer greater than, equal to, or
>   less than zero**, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater
>   than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.

So what you need is to write the if statement like

```
if ( strcmp(one, two) != 0 ) {
```

or

```
if ( !( strcmp(one, two) == 0 ) ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how `strcmp` works. To test if strings are different use

```
if(strcmp(one, two))
```

Answer (score 1):

*strcmp* returns zero when both strings are equal, it returns something other than zero when they differs, so you need to change your if in your code to something like this

```
if ( strcmp(one, two) != 0 ) {
    printf("hello world\n");
}
```