# Can someone help me with problem with sorting data structures in C-language

Tags: c, data-structures

So I've been new in structures so i tried to sort it like normal bubble sort but it won't work and also ti gives me error like "assignment with expression to array type"
I just want to sort names of cocktails in reverse way form 'z' to 'a'.
I did rest of the code which works and i got stucked on this sort

I really tried every way I could think of so if someone can help me it would be great.
Thanks :)

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20+1];
    char sast1[20+1];
    char sast2[20+1];
    char sast3[20+1];
} kokteli;

j=i;
int s;
int flag;
char *pom;

while(1) {
    flag = 0;
    for(s=0; s<j; s++) {
        if(k[s].name> k[s+1].name) {
            pom = k[s].name;
            k[s].name= k[s+1].name;
            k[s+1].name= pom;
            flag = 1;
        }
    } if(flag == 0){
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3121023 Thank you SIR!!!!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will.Thanks :)

Comment: Note that although I've duplicated the question to ones about comparing strings, you also need to use functions (`strcpy()`, `memmove()`, `memcpy()` — and maybe `strncpy()` but be cautious about it) to copy strings.  You're attempting pointer assignments on arrays — that doesn't work.  You can't assign arrays; you can't assign pointers to an array (that is, given `char array[SIZE];`, you can't do `array = "DATA";`, even when the array is part of a structure).

Comment: Thank you very much! 
@JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I've been new in structures so i tried to sort it like normal
>   bubble sort but it won't work and also ti gives me error like
>   "assignment with expression to array type"

I won't speak to what your code is actually trying to achieve but I will address the error you are getting. The compiler should be pointing out these two lines:

```
    k[s].name= k[s+1].name;
    k[s+1].name= pom;
```

So for clarity sake let's point out the fact that `k` is an array of `kokteli` structs and those structs contain members that are arrays (`name`, `sast1`, etc). `k[s].name` and `k[s+1].name` are both an array of char which in C is not assignable. You can modify the elements (`char`) of the array via pointers to the memory address for each `char` in the array. You would do that like this:

```
k[s].name[n] = //where n is an integer from 0 to 20, assign value of nth element here)
```

Let's break this statement down:

1. k is a pointer to an array of `kokteli` structs
2. `k[s]` is actually a pointer to the address of the `kokteli` struct located at the memory address offset from `k` by `s` (the exact same thing in C as `(k+s)`)
3. `k[s].name` is actually a pointer to the address of the member `name` of the `kokteli` struct located at offset `s` (can also be written in C as `(k+s)->name` or `&k[s] //since the first member is name`)
4. `k[s].name[0]` is the contents of the 0th element of the member `name` of the `kokteli` struct located at the memory address offset from `k` by `s` (can also be written in C as `*(k+s)->name`)

This is why the compiler doesn't complain about this line:

```
pom = k[s].name;
```

Now the caveat here is that the name of an array in C actually refers to a memory address for the beginning of the contents of that array. This means that *it is a pointer* itself. So since `pom` and `k[s].name` are actually both `char *`, `pom` now points to what `k[s].name` is pointing at.

Your if clause here:

```
if(k[s].name > k[s+1].name){
    ...
}
```

Is actually comparing memory addresses as `k[s].name` and `k[s+1].name` both point to the first element in the array. The difference is that one is located at a memory offset that is `sizeof(kokteli)` greater than the other (that is `k[s+1].name`) so this statement will never be `true`. I've made some code for you [here](http://tpcg.io/441d4G) that will nail this home.

As other people in the comments have pointed out, you will actually want to use strcmp (need to `#include <string.h>`) to compare the elements of the two arrays of type `char`. Reference for strcmp is located [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).

So your if clause should look something like this

```
if(strcmp(k[s].name, k[s+1].name) > 0){
    //k[s].name comes after k[s+1].name alphabetically
}
```

For more on how strcmp works, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136329/how-does-strcmp-work).