# Bubble Sort with Strings, but it's not sorting well

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I'm trying to sort an array of strings into an ascending order

```
Abcdefg
Ultimate
UMN 
Bawaw
```

i expect the result should be into:

```
Abcdefg
Bawaw
Ultimate
UMN
```

I found that bubble sort is sorting strings like :

```
Abcdefg
Bawaw
UMN
Ultimate
```

And when i try to bypass it, by turning everything into an uppercase / lowercase strings, but if i add the data, it became juggled

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    char data[8][50] = {"Abcdefg","Ultimate","UMN", "Bawaw", "Ultima Sonora", "UMN Medical Centre", "Ultima Toys","BACD"};
    char temp[10];
    int i, j;

    printf("Original data = \n");
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 50; j++){
            if(data[i][j] >= 65 && data[i][j] <= 90){
                data[i][j] += 32;
            }
        }
    }


    for(i = 0; i <8 ; i++){
        for(j = i+1; j < 8; j++)
        if(strcmp(data[i], data[j])>0){
            strcpy(temp, data[i]);
            strcpy(data[i],data[j]);
            strcpy(data[j], temp);
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted data = \n");
    for(i=0; i<8; i++){
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do anyone have a clue what's going on there?

Comment: Aside: please use `tolower()` to be found in `ctype.h`. You don't even need to test the range first. `data[i][j] = tolower(data[i][j]);`

Comment: You have string overflow. In the first test `char temp[10];` was OK to hold `"Ultimate"`, but now is too short to hold `"UMN Medical Centre"`. I suggest `char temp[50];` to match the 2D array's strings.

Comment: You might want to check if you library supports `strcmpi` - the case insensitive equivalent to `strcmp`. - this is more efficient than turning the whole string into upper or lower case.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the answer! I really appreciate it. Do you mean by the range is the number of characters in the array?

Comment: By "range" I mean the character values. You can safely pass `'2'` to `tolower` and it will return the same value - not some wierd attempt to lowercase it.

Comment: @WeatherVane ahh okay, convenient. I wonder is there also to-'uppercase' function? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Okay, will do.  Thankss

Comment: The uppercase function is somewhat unsurprisingly called `toupper()`. You might also be interested a family of functions called `isupper()` and `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first note that `temp` doesn't have enough space to hold some of your strings , so use `char temp[50]`. also since ASCII code of `l` is smaller than `m` the result you are excepting is true , so is your program , but since you have overflow ,the program will have undefined behavior. which means anything can happen.

Read this link [How dangerous is it to access an array out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646973/how-dangerous-is-it-to-access-an-array-out-of-bounds?noredirect=1&lq=1)also it's not bad to take look here [how strcmp() works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136329/how-does-strcmp-work)

Comment: thanks hanie for showing up again, I really appreciate it.  I'll also read your link recommendation well. :)

Comment: @ChristianHalim your welcome,since I'm student and I have always found help with my questions here , feel free this is purpose of SO .

Answer (score 1):

One more thing i see in your code is in the part of uppercase / lowercase strings.

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < 50; j++){
            if(data[i][j] >= 65 && data[i][j] <= 90){
                data[i][j] += 32;
            }
        }
    }
```

you should use `j < strlen(data[i]`. You can also use tolower function as the comment above.

It becomes:

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(data[i]); j++){
            data[i][j] = tolower(data[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing again to help me, & sorry for the late reply. I really appreciate you for always recommending useful functions for my code, cheers :))