# How to Compare two number-plates of a vehicle having specific format using C without inbuilt functions

Tags: c, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to compare numbers read from numberplates. Each element that I want to compare looks like "CCNNNN" where C is a character from A-Z and N is a digit from 0 to 9. For example: TS9548

It defines the following total order on such numbers. Consider two distinct numbers A=A1A2M1M2M3M4 and B=B1B2N1N2N3N4

We say A<B if either:

`A1A2 < B1B2 in alphabetic order or, A1A2 = B1B2 and M1M2M3M4 < N1N2N3N4 as integers.`

Examples:

- TS5480 < WB1915
- AP9540 < TS7480
- KL1452 < KL1457

Input Format:

Each line of the input will give two distinct numbers and separated by a space.

Input read from text file:

```
TS45678 NM78902
HJ78654 JK78901
GH00000 DE55555
```

Each line ends with a '\n' character.

Output:

For each line read,

Output 1 if A < B followed by a '\n'

Output 0 if B > A followed by a '\n'

Output -1 if B = A followed by a '\n'

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

  char numberPlate[2][8];
 
  
  
  while (scanf("%s %s",&numberPlate[0], &numberPlate[1])!=EOF){
      
      printf(numberPlate[0]);
      printf("\n");
      printf(numberPlate[1]);
    
    for (int i=0;i<=7;i++)
        
        {
            if (numberPlate[0][i]>numberPlate[1][i])
            {  
        
            printf("%s is greater than %s\n",numberPlate[0], numberPlate[1]);
        
            }
            
            else
            printf("%s is lesser than %s\n",numberPlate[0], numberPlate[1]);
        
        break;
        }
        
        
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
$ cat input.txt | ./final.exe
TS45678
NM78902TS45678 is greater than NM78902
HJ78654
JK78901HJ78654 is lesser than JK78901
GH00000
DE55555GH00000 is greater than DE55555
```

I am not able to read input as line by line which stores `TS45678` in row 1 and `NM78902` in row 2 of `numberPlate[2][8]` array..
Secondly, the  comparison functions seems incorrect.

Comment: You can use [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) on the two strings containing the license plate numbers, that will give you the correct ordering.

Comment: without using any inbuilt function.

Comment: also, I am not able to read string the way in which I want.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use `strcmp()`? Is this an assignment? Also, `printf()` and `scanf()` are also functions from the standard library. Are you also not allowed to use those?

Comment: Not working. It's giving ouput as TS45678NM78902
NM78902
HJ78654JK78901
JK78901
GH00000DE55555
DE55555

Comment: Not working. Can you test  on your side.

Comment: while (scanf("%7s %7s",numberPlate[0], numberPlate[1]) == 2){  << this is also wrong >>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does strcmp() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136329/how-does-strcmp-work)

Comment: `scanf("%s"...` is no better than `gets()`.  Use `scanf("%7s"...)` to read into a buffer of size 8.

Comment: This would be a better exercise if you used `qsort`.  You'd probably learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *minimal* changes to make your code *working*:

- a `printf("\n");` is missing

  ```
   printf(numberPlate[0]);
   printf("\n");
   printf(numberPlate[1]);
   printf("\n"); // missing
  ```
- The `for` loop breaks when the plates are not equal but the case there are equal isn't handled

  ```
   while (/* ... */)
   {
       for (i=0;i<=7;i++)     
       {
           if (numberPlate[0][i]>numberPlate[1][i])
             {
               printf("%s is greater than %s\n",numberPlate[0], numberPlate[1]);
               break; 
             }
           if (numberPlate[0][i]<numberPlate[1][i])
             { 
               printf("%s is lesser than %s\n",numberPlate[0], numberPlate[1]);
               break;
             }        
       }
       // You should handle here the case they are equal.
       // [your code here]
    }
  ```

I let you figure out what you can do to check out they are equals.

These are the *minimal* changes. As said in the comment, this code isn't robust enough to handle bad inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to use `strcmp`, write your own:

```
int strCmp(const char *a, const char *b)
{
    while (*a != '\0' && *b != '\0' && *a++ == *b++)
        ;

    return *b-*a;
}
```

This will be enough to solve your problem.